# SSE vector realign?

Tags: sse, avx, avx2

Is there a way to realign data that has been loaded into SSE/AVX vector registers (say to implement a sliding window)? Or do I need to shift the bytes myself and reload into vector registers from memory again?

Comment: Are you wanting to align them on a bitwise, byte-wise, or word-wise basis?

Comment: For 128-bit vectors, SSSE3 / AVX `palignr` works.  For AVX2, the 2x 128-bit lane behaviour is nearly useless for this.  Sometimes reloading from memory is better, though: 2/clock load throughput with no penalty if you don't cross a cache-line boundary (on Intel).

Comment: @dai either bit or bytewise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 128-bit vectors, SSSE3 / AVX [`[v]palignr xmm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/palignr) works for arbitrary byte-windows on a pair of registers.  For AVX2 `ymm` registers, the 2x 128-bit lane behaviour is nearly useless for this.  [_mm_alignr_epi8 (PALIGNR) equivalent in AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517970/mm-alignr-epi8-palignr-equivalent-in-avx2)

Sometimes reloading from memory is better, though: 2/clock load throughput with no penalty if you don't cross a cache-line boundary (on Intel) vs. 1/clock shuffle throughput.  And the throughput / latency penalty for cache-line splits isn't terrible.  If one `palignr` is sufficient, usually use it, but it's usually better to do unaligned loads instead of trying to emulate it for AVX2.