# Shift values in AVX2 register, grabbing last one from another register

Tags: x86, sse, simd, avx2

I have two AVX2 registers, for instance with following values:

```
m0 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
m1 = {8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

I need to shift `m0` grabbing last value from `m1`:

```
m0 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

Then perform some arithmetic with `m0`, and shift again:

```
m0 = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

And so on (7 times) until

```
m0 = {7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e}
```

What's the best way to do it with AVX instructions?

Given that `m0` and `m1` were loaded from contiguous memory: `0,1,...,7,8,9,...`,
will it be faster just to keep loading `m0` from memory (address of `1`, then address of `2`, ...) considering that it is cached in L1?

Comment: unaligned loads are often *very* good, especially if you have lots of vector-ALU instructions compared to the amount of loads.

Comment: Near duplicate of [\_mm\_alignr\_epi8 (PALIGNR) equivalent in AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8517970) / [How to concatenate two vector efficiently using AVX2? (a lane-crossing version of VPALIGNR)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45245732)

Answer (score 3):

I normally do something like this, for double vector shifts of up to 16 bytes:

```
m = _mm256_alignr_epi8(_mm256_permute2x128_si256(m0, m1, 0x03), m1, 4);
```

In some cases it can be more efficient to use an unaligned load instead - it tends to depend on the particular CPU and the instruction mix, so it's worth benchmarking both ways.