# How to align/rotate a 256 bit vector in AVX2?

Tags: rust, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I am working with AVX2 intrinsics and would like to get the following:

input: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

output: `[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

The following works with 128 bit vectors:

```rust
let vec1 = _mm_set_epi32(1,2,3,4);
let vec2 = _mm_alignr_epi8(vec1, 4); // shift values one position, catch at bottom
```

vec1 will give `[1,2,3,4]`
vec2 will give `[4,1,2,3]`.
This is as expected.

With 256 bit vector

```rust
let vec256_1 = _mm256_set_epi32(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
let vec256_2 = _mm256_alignr_epi8(vec256_1, 4); // shift values one position
```

vec256_1 will give `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`
vec256_2 will give `[4,1,2,3,8,5,6,7]`

So it looks to me like it is doing the 128 bit version on the low and high part.

My question is: How can I do this so that the whole 256 bits get shifted one value to the left?

Objective: how to get the following vector: `[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Comment: You for 32bit entries, you can achieve this with `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32`

Comment: @chtz Thankyou that works. For people wondering: `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(vec1, _mm256_set_epi32(0,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))` will shift your vector to the left. starting with 6 to the right.

Comment: "it looks to me like it is doing the 128 bit version on the low and high part" -- yes, in general SSE2+ operations were upgraded to AVX2 in the "two of them side-by-side" form.

Comment: `_mm256_set_epi32(8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)` or `_mm256_set_epi32(6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1)` should also work as shuffle vector, i.e., if you have a `[7,6,..,0]` you can add or subtract an offset from every entry to rotate accordingly.

Comment: `_mm_alignr_epi8` takes 2 vector inputs.  To rotate 1 vector, you'd have to use `_mm_alignr_epi8(vec1, vec1, 4)`.  Or `_mm_shuffle_epi32(vec1, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,1,0,3))` which can be more efficient without AVX (`pshufd` is a copy-and-shuffle, but `palignr` modifies its destination.) Related: [\_mm\_alignr\_epi8 (PALIGNR) equivalent in AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8517970) / semi-related general-case of `vpalignr` [How to concatenate two vector efficiently using AVX2? (a lane-crossing version of VPALIGNR)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45245732)

Comment: So a more accurate question title would be "How to **rotate** a 256-bit vector of 32-bit elements".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford a constant vector, do this:

```
__m256i rotate1( __m256i v )
{
    const __m256i perm = _mm256_setr_epi32( 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 );
    return _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32( v, perm );
}
```

If you’d rather do without memory loads, here’s another version which does what you want in 2 instructions:

```
__m256i rotate2( __m256i v )
{
    // Make another vector with 16-byte pieces flipped
    __m256i flipped = _mm256_permute2x128_si256( v, v, 0x01 );
    // With these two vectors, `vpalignr` can rotate the complete input
    return _mm256_alignr_epi8( v, flipped, 12 );
}
```

Comment: The 2-instruction version also works for rotates that aren't a multiple of 4 bytes, unlike the first one where there's no lane-crossing shuffle with granularity narrower than 32-bit until AVX-512.

Comment: I really like the rotate2 function. Thanks! only 1 extra cycle, but the load of rotate1 will most likely not be worth it unless you use rotate alot.